# How can I connect to UNC path on an external server in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, windows-explorer, ip

I am using Windows Explorer and would like to connect to a certain IP address. After that, I want to connect to a different IP address through the server.

Ex: A -> B -> C

A is my current computer. B is the first server I'm connecting to. C is the final destination. These all have separate IPs.

I've tried doing `\\<IP of B>\\<IP of C>\<Folder on C>` but it's not working. I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to accomplish is possible without mapping server C as a drive on B.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

Not sure if it helps but the IP of C is also has a DNS listing where I can just say `\\name` instead of the `\\<ip of C>`. I'd prefer to access it with the name but the IP is fine too.

Comment: You can't access a share on one server through the share on another server.

Comment: As @joeqwerty points out, not it's not possible to do what you're trying. Why not just connect directly to C?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't connect directly to C because it's an internal IP on B's network. I'll work around this problem. Thanks!